# Firebase Native Cordova Plugins

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, firebase

Firebase Analytics, Remote Config, Crash Reporting etc. only appear to be available in the native android/ios SDKs and not the web SDK.

I have not been able to find a maintained cordova plugin for the native firebase SDKs. Does anyone know if there is a cordova plugin for the native firebase SDKs, or of one in the works?

Comment: I'm also very interested by this. Since the new firebase anounced yesterday,I plan to use it for my ionic apps.

Comment: since the APIs just came out, i think it will be awhile before a new update is released

Comment: wanting for feedback too

Comment: I've submitted a support request to them. No word back from them on it yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like someone started a repositry for the native firebase v3 cordova plugin here: https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase

The author's initial primary purpose is for push notifications, but we may be able to fork it and add additional features.

Answer (score 0):

There's https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/Firebase but it's indeed a bit outdated (version 2.3.1 from Sept 30, 2015 while version 2.4.2 was out March 28, 2016 and version 3 May 18, 2016). I don't know if there's a lot to do to make it compatible with the latest 2.* SDK, but migrating to 3 might require more work.

Another issue with using the Web SDK is when saving data:

> The Firebase Realtime Database web APIs do not persist data offline
>   outside of the session.

so if you close your app before everything was saved, you'll lose things. There's no such note on the native SDKs.